# Python SQLite Получение значения из столбца

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

Есть датабаза
Используя команду fetchone, получаю:
('20192018', '1')
Задача: Получить только второе число
База:
ID: 20192018
BALANCE: 1

Comment: Код: conn = sqlite3.connect("balances.db") # или :memory: чтобы сохранить в RAM
cursor = conn.cursor()

user_id = ("20192018")


sql = "SELECT * FROM list WHERE ID LIKE '" + (user_id) + ("'")

cursor.execute(sql)

print(cursor.fetchone())

conn.commit()
conn.close()

Comment: Пожалуйста, перенесите код из комментария в тело вопроса кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1041696/edit).

Comment: И не пишите подобные "SELECT * FROM list WHERE ID LIKE '" + (user_id) + ("'")  запросы в базу, обязательно почитайте про sql-инъекции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
sql = "select balance from list where id like ?"

params = ("20192018", )

cursor.execute(sql, params)

balance, = cursor.fetchone()
```